# Python imread bug: "Unsupported BMP bitfields layout"

Tags: python, image, imread

I seem to have encountered a bug in scipy.misc.imread, and I'm looking for a workaround.  Here's a clip of the error report:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
im = imread('380.bmp')
...

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py in _bitmap(self, header, offset)
145                     raw_mode = MASK_MODES[(file_info['bits'], file_info['rgb_mask'])]
146                 else:
--> 147                     raise IOError("Unsupported BMP bitfields layout")
148             else:
149                 raise IOError("Unsupported BMP bitfields layout")

OSError: Unsupported BMP bitfields layout
```

I can open the image without problems in an image viewer, so I'm sure it's not corrupted.

The main question is: What's the best alternative to imread, so I can get around this issue?  Alternatively, if you know a way to fix imread, that would also be good.

By the way, I'm using Python 3.5.1 in Anaconda 2.4.1 (64 bit)

Comment: You could run ImageMagick at the commandline to convert your broken BMP file into a happier PNG using this command `convert StupidBrokenPieceOfMicrosoftJunk.bmp sensible.png`

Comment: Just to confirm that ImageMagick has no problem converting that for you - I tested it. If you have lots of unhappy BMP files, you could run `mogrify -format png *.bmp` and that will make a PNG format copy of all the BMP files in your current directory - I guess you could do that in a Python startup script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the tip.  The mogrification is actually what I ended up doing (I had several hundred bmps to work with).  It's a good workaround, but I hope this problem gets to the ears the pylab folks anyway...

Comment: My pleasure - glad it worked out for you. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same error while using PIL.Image. I bypassed the issue using cv2.
My code is something like this:

```
import cv2 #pip install opencv-python
from PIL import Image #pip install pillow
temp_img = cv2.imread(filename.bmp)
color_corrected = cv2.cvtColor(temp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = Image.fromarray(color_corrected)
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this same error while using PIL.Image.

This error message is a bit generic and there are a lot of possibilities of what went wrong, but in my case it was a bitmap that was in fact valid and therefore should have been supported. I filed an issue on PIL's Github and they agreed it was a bug and gave me a fix. See https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6435 .

Hopefully the fix will be released in a future version of PIL (>= 9.3.0).